# Castle Windsor only execute certain types of Installers across many projects

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

We have a large monolithic legacy application with around 45 projects with several different composition roots (console, web, api apps).  Most component registration is done in the composition roots of the apps and many WindsorInstallers. We want to remove component registration from the composition roots and into WindsorInstallers for each project in the solution so we no longer need to modify the composition roots when we add a new project, each project should be responsible for its own component registration. We are looking to incrementally make this change to our code base because I tried just having Castle Windsor scan all of our assemblies and run all of our Installers, but that caused a myriad of issues that will need to be looked into over time.

With all of that said, we are looking for a way to only run certain installers, so we can go back a fix the broken ones over time, but all new ones will automatically be used.  Below is the approach I was headed towards, but cannot figure out or do not even know if it is possible.

All composition roots would have something like this so that all Installers are always ran.

```
container.Install(
            FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(HttpRuntime.BinDirectory))
        );
```

However I would like this install code to only run Installers of type IAutoInstaller.  In this way I could go back and fix my legacy installers just by changing the interface to IAutoInstaller and then would never need to modify the composition roots.

```
public interface IAutoInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{

}

public class ScheduledPaymentInstaller : IAutoInstaller
{

    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("DryFly.ScheduledPayments")
            .Pick()
            .WithServiceDefaultInterfaces().LifestylePerWebRequest());

    }
}
```

In summary what I am after is a way to auto execute certain installers from the composition root so that when I add new projects I do not need to modify that code.  I would just need to add a new Installer to the new project. Is there a different approach to solve this problem or can this be done via Castle Windsor?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not pretty:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
var installers = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
         .GetAssemblies() // Load all assemblies in the current application domain
         .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes()) // project all types contained in all assemblies into a single collection
         .Where(type => typeof(IAutoInstaller).IsAssignableFrom(type) && type.IsClass) // find all types that implement IAutoInstaller and are classes (this filters out the interface itself)
         .Select(Activator.CreateInstance) // project all types into instances - this relies on all of them containing a parameterless constructor
         .Cast<IAutoInstaller>(); // project the Ienumerable<object> into an Ienumerable<IAutoInstaller>

foreach (var installer in installers)
{
    installer.Install(container, container.Kernel.ConfigurationStore);
}
```

There is a massive caveat here, which is that your installers must have a parameterless constructor for this to work. If for some reason this isn't the case, your problem becomes a lot harder to solve generically.

Unfortunately, the `IWindsorInstaller` interface only enforces a method expecting the container itself, and an implementation of `IConfigurationStore`. So even if you're not using a configuration store, you still have to supply it. Luckily, when you instantiate a `WindsorContainer` using the default constructor, it wires up a default Kernel with a `DefaultConfigurationStore` implementation. This allows you to just pass that in.

If, however, you are using a custom Configuration Store (such as when using an XML configuration interpreter), and this configuration store is owned by another container, or a parent or child container related to your current container, and you require access to the values of that particular store in your particular installer, you'll have to pass that particular store reference into the installer.

As you can see from the list of caveats around the store, you are probably safe to just pass in the kernel default, or even new up a `DefaultConfigurationStore`.

Comment: I'm assuming this code is run from the composition root, correct?  If so, how do I get an instance of the store(IConfigurationStore)?

Comment: Correct. I have also updated my answer in two ways. I've elaborated on what the store actually is, and going by your comment I'm assuming you don't really need one. In which case the code I provided should suffice. Secondly, I've had a derp moment and gave you a snippet that would iterate over all your installers twice, once for the `ToList()` call and once for the `Foreach()`. If your list of installers is comfortably small it wouldn't really make a difference but I've reverted it to a normal foreach anyways.

Comment: I realised that using the current app domain would not give you all assemblies, as they are lazy loaded when the reference is resolved. I'll have a look later today on how to load everything from your bin folder instead.

Comment: Ah, you are right.  AppDomain.CurrentDomain       .GetAssemblies() only loads the assemblies referenced in the current projects bin directory.   I'm having a hard to finding how to load all dlls from the entire solution.  Is this even possible?